# Where did the UWP certificates go?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

When building a UWP app (or a packaging app - UWP for Win32) we would get a test folder with an appxbundle file which we could install on our computer for testing. But along with it we would also get a cert so that we don't get the warning that the app is untrusted. I notice that now (since a Visual Studio update?) we don't get the certificate anymore. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create one in `Package.appmanifest` - `Packaging`

[image]